# How to mutate with a column of string of decimal intervals like "[1.25-2.43]" into a column of the length of these intervals in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

How to mutate with a column of string of decimal intervals like "[1.25-2.43]" into a column of the length of these intervals in R?

Not sure why it continues to show strange errors when I do str_split inside mutate. Clearly they don't work together for some weird reason.

Comment: Can you please share reproducible example using `dput` and your expected output.

Comment: str_split is returnng a list. Its better to use substr .

Comment: But I want the two ends for my calculation. Substring can only return on result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that computes the absolute difference between the two numbers in strings following the format in the question.

```
intervalLength <- function(x){
  y <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", x)
  sapply(strsplit(y, "-"), function(x) abs(diff(as.numeric(x))))
}

x <- "[1.25-2.43]"
intervalLength(x)
#[1] 1.18
```

Another example.

```
set.seed(2021)
x2 <- round(runif(5, 0, 2), 2)
x2 <- paste0("[", x2, "-", x2 + round(runif(5, 0, 2), 2), "]")
x2
#[1] "[0.9-2.3]"   "[1.57-2.85]" "[1.42-1.95]" "[0.76-2.39]" "[1.27-3.24]"

intervalLength(x2)
#[1] 1.40 1.28 0.53 1.63 1.97
```

---

### Edit

The question asks about `dplyr::mutate`. The function above can be used in a `mutate` instruction.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, Num = x2)
df1 %>% mutate(x3 = intervalLength(Num))
#  A         Num   x3
#1 1   [0.9-2.3] 1.40
#2 2 [1.57-2.85] 1.28
#3 3 [1.42-1.95] 0.53
#4 4 [0.76-2.39] 1.63
#5 5 [1.27-3.24] 1.97
```